# Docker-compose does not install properly on Ubuntu 14.04—line 1: {error:Not Found}

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` and I followed the exact steps of [official docker-compose installation manual](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

```
sudo su
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/VERSION_NUM/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

But unfortunately, executing `docker-compose` gave me an `command not found` error.

```
shibin@87:~$ docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: line 1: {error:Not Found}: command not found
```

I tried open the `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` file and it indeed shows:

```
{error:Not Found}: command not found
```

Thus I guess docker-compose not properly installed, anyone has met the same issue?

Comment: If you have problems installing with curl, you can use pip instead: `pip install -U docker-compose`

Comment: I just needed to log out and log back in

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have problems installing with curl, you can use pip instead:

```
pip install -U docker-compose
```

Then you need apply executable permissions to the binary:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Let me know if the problem is fixed or not.

Comment: Works for me in armbian.

Answer (score 8):

You have to replace VERSION_NUM with the version number of the release from [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases). At the time of writing this answer, the version number is 1.4.2. So your commands become:

```
sudo su
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.4.2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: @NicBarker turns out I can't use curl in this computer, so the answer using `pip` works for me. Both are correct answers :)

Comment: This can also happen if the long curl command gets split across two commands in your paste. You will need to make sure that it is a single command in order for it to install properly.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and the solution was simply:

```
sudo ln /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin
```

Comment: I still getting that no such file like docker-compose and your answer was helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

First.

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip
```

Then.

```
sudo pip install docker-compose
```

Comment: Why would you install docker-compose globally using `sudo`? You really ought to install it into a `virtualenv` for sanity.

Comment: This gave me "ERROR: client and server don't have same version (client : 1.25, server: 1.18)" when I tried to start a container